# Delete cached data from DVC

Tags: dvc

I would like to be able to delete individual files or folders from the `DVC` cache, after they have been pulled with `dvc pull`, so they don't occupy space in local disk.

Let me make things more concrete and summarize the solutions I found so far. Imagine you have downloaded a data folder using something like:

```bash
dvc pull <my_data_folder.dvc>
```

This will place the downloaded data into `.dvc/cache`, and it will create a set of soft links in `my_data_folder` (if you have configured DVC to use soft links)

```bash
ls -l my_data_folder
```

You will see something like:

```
my_data_file_1.pk --> .dvc/cache/4f/7bc7702897bec7e0fae679e968d792
my_data_file_2.pk --> .dvc/cache/4f/7bc7702897bec7e0fae679e968d792
...
```

Imagine you don't need this data for a while, and you need to free its space from local disk. I know of two manual approaches for doing that, although I am not sure about the second one:

##### Preliminary step (optional)

Not needed if you have symlinks (which I believe is true, at least in unix-like OS):

```bash
dvc unprotect my_data_folder
```

##### Approach 1 (verified):

Delete all the cached data. From the repo's root folder:

```bash
rm -r my_data_folder
rm -rf .dvc/cache
```

This seems to work properly, and will completely free the disk space previously used by the downloaded data. Once we need the data again, we can pull it by doing `dvc pull` as previously. The drawback is that we are removing all the data downloaded with `dvc` so far, not only the data corresponding to `my_data_folder`, so we would need to do `dvc pull` for all the data again.

##### Approach 2 (NOT verified):

Delete only specific files (to be thoroughly tested that this does not corrupt `DVC` in any way):

First, take note of the path indicated in the soft link:

```bash
ls -l my_data_folder
```

You will see something like:

```
my_data_file_1.pk --> .dvc/cache/4f/7bc7702897bec7e0fae679e968d792
my_data_file_2.pk --> .dvc/cache/4f/7bc7702897bec7e0fae679e968d792
```

If you want to delete my_data_file_1.pk, from the repo's root folder run:

```bash
rm .dvc/cache/4f/7bc7702897bec7e0fae679e968d792
```

##### Note on `dvc gc`

For some reason, running `dvc gc` does not seem to delete the files from the cache, at least in my case.

I would appreciate if someone can suggest a better way, or also comment whether the second approach is actually appropriate. Also, if I want to delete the whole folder and not go file by file, is there any way to do that automatically?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible at the moment to granularly specify a directory / file to be  removed from the cache. Here are the tickets to vote and ask to prioritize this:

- [dvc gc remove](https://github.com/iterative/dvc/issues/4218)
- [Reconsider gc implementation](https://github.com/iterative/dvc/issues/2325)

> For some reason, running dvc gc does not seem to delete the files from the cache, at least in my case.

This is a bit concerning. If you run it with the [`-w`](https://dvc.org/doc/command-reference/gc#-w) option it keeps *only* files / dirs that are referenced in the current versions of the `.dvc` and `dvc.lock` files. And it should remove everything else.

So, let's say you are building a model:

`my_model_file.pk`

You created it once and its hash is `4f7bc7702897bec7e0fae679e968d792` and it's written in the `dvc.lock` or in the `my_model_file.dvc`.

Then you do another iteration and now hash is different `5a8cc7702897bec7e0faf679e968d363`. It should be now written in the `.dvc` or lock. It means that a model that corresponds to the previous `4f7bc7702897bec7e0fae679e968d792` is not referenced anymore. In this case `dvc gc -w` should definitely collect it. If that is not happening please create a ticket and we'll try to reproduce and take a look.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will vote on the mentioned issues. Just one question: do you know if the approach 2 I discussed is appropriate? (this is to delete the specific files from .dvc/cache based on the hash indicated in the symlink, something like `rm .dvc/cache/4f/7bc7702897bec7e0fae679e968d792`? Regarding using `dvc gc`, now I understand it better based on your response. I understood originally that the objective was to free space from files/folders that are no longer needed at all, not even their latest version. I didn't try for deleting previous versions.